# Algebraic Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi I am struggling with solving this, I am 12 years old and am trying to work my way through extended maths IGCSE, but have been stumped by this for a few days:

$\dfrac{13x + 2}{(2x + 1)(x - 1)} =\dfrac{A}{2x + 1} + \dfrac{B}{x - 1}$, what are the value of A and B?

I have the answer, A = 3 and B = 5

Comment: Multiply it out on RHS, you will have in the numerator: $A(x-1)+B(2x+1)$ and now compare the coefficients of various powers of $x$ on both sides. Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: Multiply by $x-1$ and evaluate at $x=1$. You get $\frac{13+2}{3}=B$. Then multiply by $2x+1$ and evaluate at $x=-1/2$. You get $\frac{13(-1/2)+2}{-1/2-1}=A$.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you use:
$$A(x-1)+B(2x+1)=13x+2$$
Then solve $A$ and $B$ using the values of x:
$$x-1=0\Rightarrow x=1$$
$$2x+1=0 \Rightarrow x=-\frac12$$

Answer (score 2):

$$A(x-1)+B(2x+1)=x(A+2B)-A+B=13x+2$$ From here we have a system for $A$ and $B$ (two polynomials are equal when corresponding coefficients are equal). Thus, $A+2B=13$ and $-A+B=2$, $A=3$, $B=5$